# Why does ghci give me a type for "1 ++ 2" instead of ragequitting?

Tags: haskell

GHCI will give me a type for `1 ++ 2`:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.4.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :t 1 ++ 2
1 ++ 2 :: Num [a] => [a]
```

But this is obviously wrong. If I try and evaluate it, instead of just type check it, things correctly fail:

```
Prelude> 1 ++ 2

<interactive>:3:1:
    No instance for (Num [a0])
      arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [a0])
    In the first argument of `(++)', namely `1'
    In the expression: 1 ++ 2
    In an equation for `it': it = 1 ++ 2
```

What gives?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> But this is obviously wrong.

No, it's completely correct.

The type of `(++)` is

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

and the type of integer literals is

```
1 :: Num n => n
```

So the type `[a]` that an argument of `(++)` must have is unified with the type `Num n => n` that a literal has, giving

```
1 ++ 2 :: Num [a] => [a]
```

and if you have a list type with a `Num` instance, that expression can also be evaluated.

But, by default, there is no `Num` instance for list types available, so when you try to evaluate it, ghci complains that it finds no `Num` instance for `[a]`.

For example:

```
Prelude> instance Num a => Num [a] where fromInteger n = Data.List.genericReplicate n 1 

<interactive>:2:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `+'
    In the instance declaration for `Num [a]'

<interactive>:2:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `*'
    In the instance declaration for `Num [a]'

<interactive>:2:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `abs'
    In the instance declaration for `Num [a]'

<interactive>:2:10: Warning:
    No explicit method or default declaration for `signum'
    In the instance declaration for `Num [a]'
Prelude> 1 ++ 2 :: [Int]
[1,1,1]
```

Comment: So does that mean ghci isn't fully type checking the expression? What's the step that isn't being made by ghci to go from Num [a] to "there is no Num [a]"?

Comment: It infers (and checks) the type as far as it can be inferred. What it doesn't do is checking if the instances currently in scope allow the type variables to be instantiated in a way that would yield a well-typed monomorphic expression. That's good, since sometimes you want to check what type an expression has without having defined necessary instances to evaluate such an expression. When the expression shall be evaluated, the type variables have to be instantiated to get a monomorphic type, and then ghci looks for the necessary instances. If instances are missing, that is reported.

Comment: A `No instance ...` message doesn't mean that the expression is inherently not-well-typed, it is (real type errors get different messages); by adding the missing instances, you can (almost always) get ghci to accept and evaluate it.

Answer (score 16):

Because someone *could* define lists to be treated as numbers:

```
instance Num a => Num [a] where
 (+) = zipWith (+)
 (*) = zipWith (*)
 (-) = zipWith (-)
 negate = map negate
 abs = map abs
 signum = map signum
 fromInteger x = [fromInteger x]
```

Then what you typed would work, since

```
  1++2 == fromInteger 1++fromInteger 2 == [1]++[2]
```

(Not that this `Num` instance would make much sense..)

Comment: You can define a mostly sensible `Num` instance for all applicatives `T` (including `[]` and `((->) e)`): `instance (Num a) => Num (T a) where fromInteger = pure . fromInteger; negate = liftA negate; (+) = liftA2 (+); ...`

Comment: @melpomene I thought that concrete example would be best here.